# TypeScript not building with Azure Hosted Agent

Tags: typescript, npm, azure-devops, typescript-typings, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an ASP.NET MVC application written in .Net5.

This uses typescript files and I have NuGet package references to the following:

```
<PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="3.2.449" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="4.0.3">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build" Version="2.1.113" />
```

In my project I have:

- Folder called `node-modules` (not pushed to Azure Devops)
- bundleconfig.json
- gulpfile.js
- libman.json
- package.json (+ package-lock.json)

The `package.json` is:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "del": "5.1.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "4.5.0",
    "@types/google.visualization": "0.0.53",
    "@types/jquery": "3.5.1",
    "@types/jqueryui": "1.12.13",
    "@types/jquery.datatables": "1.10.36",
    "@types/jquery.ui.datetimepicker": "0.3.29"
  }
}
```

When I compile in Visual Studio 2019 (latest) it compiles perfectly, everything works as expected.

I did however get in the Build Output (Information):

> Package restore on project open is disabled. Change the npm package
> management settings in Project Properties to enable restore on project
> open.

I found the setting "Restore On Project Save" and changed this to `true`.  That added the following to my csproj file:

```
<ProjectExtensions><VisualStudio><UserProperties appsettings_1qaf_1json__JsonSchema="https://gitpod.io/schemas/gitpod-schema.json" NpmRestoreOnProjectOpen="True" /></VisualStudio></ProjectExtensions>
```

I pushed this up to Azure DevOps, but when the agent builds it (some steps removed for clarity):

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    clean: true
```

I get the following error:

> ##[error]MyApp\Scripts\MyTypeScript.ts(13,9): Error TS2581: Build:Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type
> definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.

So, the hosted agent is evidently not retrieving the types.  I'm guessing I need to adjust my YAML file, but unsure how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message and the Yaml definition, it seems that you are missing the steps of **NPM Install** to install required npm packages.

VSBuild task itself can only restore nuget packages but cannot install npm package, so you need to add additional tasks to install npm packages.

Here is my example: you could try to add a [Npm Install task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=azure-devops) before the VSBuild task.

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    workingDir: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
    verbose: false


- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    clean: true
```

**Result:**

It could work fine.

[image]

Comment: Solved for me.  Just FYI, the package.json file was in the same path as my *.csproj file, so I just had to amend the answer above to have `workingDir: 'MyApplicationName'`.